# Unable to delete Key Value properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to delete few Key/value, for example "AssociatePublicIpAddress":true   from the output and want to keep rest of the output same to send back into a function later.

```
md_NetworkInterfaces=response["RestoreMetadata"]["NetworkInterfaces"]  
print(md_NetworkInterfaces)
print(type(md_NetworkInterfaces))
```

> [{"AssociatePublicIpAddress":true,"DeleteOnTermination":true,"Description":"Primary network interface","DeviceIndex":0,"Groups":["sg-0b11476a38d83dba3","sg-80e269f9"],"Ipv6AddressCount":0,"Ipv6Addresses":[],"NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-45fe4079","PrivateIpAddress":"172.31.38.42","PrivateIpAddresses":[{"Primary":true,"PrivateIpAddress":"172.31.38.42"}],"SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount":0,"SubnetId":"subnet-3d03d94b","InterfaceType":"interface","Ipv4Prefixes":[],"Ipv6Prefixes":[]}]
> <class 'str'>

How Can I delete  that key value pair? `"AssociatePublicIpAddress":true`

After reading some document I tried to convert it to json object and pop value out, but when i send remaining output back into the API it gives below error, so i might be doing something wrong in conversion steps.

Any help will be great.

> Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`) at [Source: (String){DeleteOnTermination: true, Description: Primary network interface, DeviceIndex: 0, Groups: [sg-0b11476a38d83dba3, sg-80e269f9], Ipv6AddressCount: 0, Ipv6Addresses: [], PrivateIpAddresses: [{Primary: true, PrivateIpAddress: 172.31.38.42}], SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount: 0, SubnetId: subnet-3d03d94b, InterfaceType: interface, Ipv4Prefixes: [], Ipv6Prefixes: []}; line: 1, column: 1]

Function I pass it back is this.

```
response = backup_client.start_restore_job(
RecoveryPointArn=recovery_arn,
Metadata={

            'VpcId' : md_VpcId,
            'Monitoring': md_Monitoring,
            'CapacityReservationSpecification' : md_CapacityReservationSpecification,
            'InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior': md_InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior,
            'DisableApiTermination' : md_DisableApiTermination,
            'KeyName' : md_KeyName,
            'CreditSpecification' : md_CreditSpecification,
            'HibernationOptions' : md_HibernationOptions,
            'EbsOptimized' : md_EbsOptimized,
            'Placement' : md_Placement,
            'aws:backup:request-id' : md_aws_backup_request_id,
            'InstanceType': md_InstanceType,
            'NetworkInterfaces' : md_NetworkInterfaces
    },
            IamRoleArn='arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/service-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole',

            ResourceType='EC2',
            CopySourceTagsToRestoredResource=True
    )
```

=================

RESOLVED>

```
my_list = json.loads(md_NetworkInterfaces) 
pop_keys =['AssociatePublicIpAddress','NetworkInterfaceId','PrivateIpAddress'] 
dict1=my_list[0] for key in pop_keys: dict1.pop(key, None) 
my_list[0]=dict1 
thislist = [] thislist.insert(1, my_list[0]) 
resultnew=json.dumps(thislist)
```

Comment: See [how to remove a key from a dict](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-remove-key-from-dictionary/).

Comment: Fixed.

        my_list = json.loads(md_NetworkInterfaces)
        
        pop_keys =['AssociatePublicIpAddress','NetworkInterfaceId','PrivateIpAddress']

        dict1=my_list[0]
        for key in pop_keys:
                dict1.pop(key, None)
        my_list[0]=dict1
        thislist = []
        thislist.insert(1, my_list[0])
        
        
        resultnew=json.dumps(thislist)

Comment: Glad to know you fixed your problem. Feel free to post your own Answer if you think it will help future readers. Or, if it was caused by a mistake or typo, feel free to Delete your Question.